# I can't figure out why my filler spaces aren't being displayed in my COBOL application

Tags: cobol, spacing

Ok so I'm making this application for school, which requires a certain format of spacing between the entries read in from .txt file.  I've created the header using the filler term and the spacing works just fine, however when I apply the same method to the formatting of the records imported from the .txt it doesn't seem to work.  I've tried everything under the sun and I can't make it work for the life of me!

This is what the output looks like now:

```
PARTNUMBER  PARTNAME     QUANTITY  VALUE

1111111screws robertson 10 43210200Ajax          
2222222screws robertson 08 41000100Ajax          
2222233screws robertson 06 43210200Ajax          
3333333screws robertson 04 41000100Ajax          
4444444bolts dead 10       43210200Robo          
5555555bolts dead 80       01000100Robo
```

But, it should be something like:

```
PARTNUMBER PARTNAME     QUANTITY  VALUE

1111111   screws robertson 10     43210200 Ajax          
2222222   screws robertson 08     41000100 Ajax          
2222233   screws robertson 06     43210200 Ajax          
3333333   screws robertson 04     41000100 Ajax          
4444444   bolts dead       10     43210200 Robo          
5555555   bolts dead.      80     01000100 Robo
```

Below is the code that I think I need to make this happen, but again I'm just not sure why it isn't working

```
 FILE SECTION.
   FD  INVENT-FILE-IN.
   01  INVENT-RECORD-IN PIC X(49).


   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  DISPLAY-HEADERS.
       05  DISPLAY-PART-NUMBER PIC A(11)
           VALUE "PARTNUMBER".
       05  FILLER              PIC X(1).
       05  DISPLAY-PART-NAME   PIC A(9)
           VALUE "PARTNAME".
       05  FILLER              PIC X(4). 
       05  DISPLAY-QUANTITY    PIC A(8)
           VALUE  "QUANTITY".
       05  FILLER              PIC X(2).
       05  DISPLAY-VALUE       PIC A(5)      
           VALUE "VALUE".

   01  DISPLAY-RECORDS.
       05  WS-INVENTORY-PART-NUMBER   PIC 9(7).
       05  FILLER                     PIC X(4) VALUE SPACES.
       05  WS-INVENTORY-PART-NAME     PIC X(20).
       05  FILLER                     PIC X(4) VALUE SPACES.
       05  WS-INVENTORY-QUANTITY      PIC 9(4).
       05  FILLER                     PIC X(2) VALUE SPACES.
       05  WS-INVENTORY-VALUE         PIC 9(8).
       05  FILLER                     PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
       05  WS-INVENTORY-SUPPLIER-CODE PIC X(5). 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   100-PROCESS-INVENTORY-FILE.
       PERFORM  201-OPEN-INVENT-FILE.
       PERFORM  202-DISPLAY-HEADER.
       PERFORM  204-INPUT-INVENT-FILE
       PERFORM  206-DISPLAY-RECORDS
                     UNTIL EOF-SWITCH = "Y".
       PERFORM  205-TERMINATE-INVENTORY-FILE.
       STOP RUN.

   201-OPEN-INVENT-FILE.
       OPEN INPUT INVENT-FILE-IN.

   202-DISPLAY-HEADER.
       DISPLAY DISPLAY-HEADERS.


   206-DISPLAY-RECORDS.
       MOVE INVENT-RECORD-IN TO DISPLAY-RECORDS.
       DISPLAY DISPLAY-RECORDS.

       READ INVENT-FILE-IN
           AT END 
               MOVE "Y" TO EOF-SWITCH
           NOT AT END
               COMPUTE READ-COUNTER = READ-COUNTER + 1
       END-READ.

   204-INPUT-INVENT-FILE.
       READ INVENT-FILE-IN
           AT END 
               MOVE "Y" TO EOF-SWITCH
           NOT AT END
               COMPUTE READ-COUNTER = READ-COUNTER + 1
       END-READ.

   205-TERMINATE-INVENTORY-FILE.
       CLOSE  INVENT-FILE-IN.
```

Comment: In the first line of 206, you move the input record to DISPLAY-RECORDS, destroying the filler spaces.  You have to define the input fields and move them to the 05 DISPLAY-RECORDS fields separately.

Answer (score 3):

As previously stated in the comments, in paragraph 206-DISPLAY-RECORDS, you are moving the entire input record to DISPLAY-RECORDS.

The problem here is that your input record is not formatted the same as your output record. This just means that you have to format it yourself. The easiest way to do this is to define your input input record differently. Something like this should do the trick:

```
 FILE SECTION.
   FD  INVENT-FILE-IN.
   01  INVENT-RECORD-IN.
       05  INVENT-PART-NUMBER   PIC 9(7).
       05  INVENT-PART-NAME     PIC X(20).
       05  INVENT-QUANTITY      PIC 9(4).
       05  INVENT-VALUE         PIC 9(8).
       05  INVENT-SUPPLIER-CODE PIC X(5).
```

From here, its as easy as moving this fields to their equivalent spot in you DISPLAY-RECORDS:

```
   206-DISPLAY-RECORDS.
       MOVE INVENT-PART-NUMBER   TO WS-INVENTORY-PART-NUMBER   
       MOVE INVENT-PART-NAME     TO WS-INVENTORY-PART-NAME
       MOVE INVENT-QUANTITY      TO WS-INVENTORY-QUANTITY
       MOVE INVENT-VALUE         TO WS-INVENTORY-VALUE
       MOVE INVENT-SUPPLIER-CODE TO WS-INVENTORY-SUPPLIER-CODE 

       READ INVENT-FILE-IN
           AT END 
               MOVE "Y" TO EOF-SWITCH
           NOT AT END
               COMPUTE READ-COUNTER = READ-COUNTER + 1
       END-READ.
```

Comment: can you please add the `MOVE CORRESPONDING` variant to your answer to make it even more useful?